# Google Sheets: Performing IF On Date Time Cells

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, time, string-formatting, number-formatting

Is there a way to perform an =IF function on a cell in google sheets that determines if the time of the date time cell equals a particular time regardless of date equals a certain value?

Comment: You may use `TEXT()` and `TIMEVALUE()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example:

```
=IF(TEXT(A1, "hh:mm")="17:34", "x", "y")
```

where A1 is for example:

```
12/12/2020 17:33:55
```

Comment: ~Can I do greater and less than with this?~ I can!

Comment: @memtech3 this should do: `=IF(TEXT(A1, "hh:mm")*1>"17:34"*1, "x", "y")`